# How to test meta name="theme-color" tag dynamic changes on desktop?

Tags: android, web, frontend, google-chrome-devtools

I have an app that change meta name="theme-color" content value dynamically to match background color. So the precise timing is critical.

Though I can test its behaviour on mobile device, it would be great to have a tool to do this in desktop chrome using dev tools or any other way on work station where I do the coding.

I know about Chrome remote debug Android devices, but it buggy and I still hope there is no need to connect a separate device every time I need to deal with theme color.